# <Unable to read data> SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Something very strange is happening on my AZURE SQL Server.

I have a table that I query from SQL Server Management Studio, from a specific IP (whitelisted at AZURE). This table only contains 265 records. One of the fields is an nvarchar(MAX).

When I edit the rows, they show up perfectly. If I scroll up the table, everything is fine, but when I scroll down, a random record shows up with the legend  o several fields, while other fields have Chinese characters on it. This is WITHOUT refreshing the query, but just scrolling up and then down.

Here is a screenshot of one record (only happens on one record at a time)

[image]

The first time it happened, I thought "Ok, I got hacked" but then I realized the record went back to normal when I executed the query again. I scrolled up to see if everything was fine on all 265 records, and another record filled out with what I believe are Chinese characters showed up.

While writing this Question, another one just showed up:

[image]

When I translated part of this last one that just showed up, I got this at Google:

[image]

Am I being hacked? The backend is a .Net Core API.

Thanks.

Comment: You have provided no information at all. What table is this, what is it supposed to contain? Who stores data in there? What application? Does that application try to "fix" some non-existent Unicode issue and ends up mangling the text? Or was it actually used to insert Chinese text?

Comment: This question was voted to be closed because someone believes I need to add more information. I added all the necessary information. It is an azure SQL Server Im connecting to thru SQL Server Management Studio (remotely), and Im also explaining the scenario where this issue is taking place.

Comment: You haven't added any information. `There's chines in there` isn't information. For all we know that's legitimate data entered by the users. Or there's no security on the database, no VPN or firewall, the database is exposed to the public iIternet and someone started writing text in there. You're asking people to guess

Comment: Read the post again, and you will find out all the answers to your questions. It is not an application, it is SQL Server Management Studio connecting to a remote Azure SQL Server. Thanks.

Comment: Please, read my post, it is pretty clear. IT IS SQL Server MANAGEMENT STUDIO, changing the content of a view when I scroll up or down.

Comment: I repeat, there's no information. It's quite possible that SSMS can't display that data. SSMS **is a client application** itself, it's not SQL Server. If the data is too long it won't be displayed. If the connection is bad and packets are dropped, the data may appear mangled. As for the Chinese text, we just can't guess where that came from.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Kanavos. I appreciate your help. I will wait for someone else's response. Have a good day.

Comment: Have you actually tried executing a query and checking the results *with another tool*? SSMS *won't* display all the data, especially when you tell it the data may be 4GB long - that's what `nvarchar(max)` means. SSMS is a management tool, not a generic data entry tool. If you search for `Unable to Read Data` you'll find [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724758/how-to-query-for-rows-containing-unable-to-read-data-in-a-column)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, *If the connection is bad and packets are dropped, the data may appear mangled.*?? Not unless TCP/IP has been changed.  Its whole purpose  is reliable data transport.

Comment: I thought that too James when I saw his/her Q but notice he/she is saying that the records get corrupted when scrolling up/down, not when querying again. He also has an nvarchar(max) field for which we dont know the content. I believe he is querying sql remotely and trying to reproduce too much info on screen. As for the translation he is googling I believe it is just an unfortunate coincidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the amount of data you are querying and SQL Server Management Studio rendering it. Remove the `nvarchar(max)` field from the SQL query and it won't happen again.

Comment: Googling for `Unable to read data` shows there are [similar questions in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724758/how-to-query-for-rows-containing-unable-to-read-data-in-a-column)

Comment: I ment "re-rendering". Sorry.

Comment: I saw that question Panagioti, it is about finding those records, which is not my issue since those record do not exist on my table.