# how to convert nvarchar(50) to datetime in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, converters

hi i wrote  this query in SqlServer 2008
but some thing goes wrong

```
select * from News_Table
where (DATEDIFF( DAY ,convert(datetime, NewsDate) , convert(datetime,@Todaydate )) <= @Count)
```

that  `@NewsDate` and `@Todaydate` are two nvarchar parameters that are saved like this `2014/11/16`

running this query give me an error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
```

Comment: Why is a `@Todaydate` parameter a varchar and not a datetime in the first place?

Comment: because my Tables are filled from c# code and users so it should be a nvarchar and in another hand i am using hijri dates there was no way to use datetime...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124187/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the correct style parameter to your convert function (see MSDN: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) )

ie `CONVERT(DATETIME, NewsDate, 111)`  (111 is the style for YYYY/MM/DD)

Then you get:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  News_Table
WHERE (DATEDIFF( DAY ,
                 CONVERT(DATETIME, NewsDate, 111) , 
                 CONVERT(DATETIME,@Todaydate, 111)
               ) <= @Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

To know more [click here](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/SQL/howtoformatdatetime.php)

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '2014/11/16', 111) as datetime
```

**OP**

[image]

So your query would be like this

```
Select * from News_Table
where (DATEDIFF( DAY ,convert(datetime, '2014/11/16', 111) , convert(datetime,@Todaydate,111 )) <= @Count)
```

Comment: i used 131 ty for help

Answer (score 1):

use `Convert(datetime, @yourvalue, 111)`

```
select * from News_Table
where (DATEDIFF( DAY ,convert(datetime, @NewsDate, 111) , convert(datetime,@Todaydate, 111 )) <= @Count)
```

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM News_Table
WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(NewsDate AS Datetime),CAST(@Todaydate AS Datetime)) <= @Count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like this to convert that string into DATETIME datatype

```
DECLARE @Date NVARCHAR(20) = '2013/11/16'

SELECT CAST((LEFT(@Date, 4) + SUBSTRING(@Date, 6 ,2) + RIGHT(@Date, 2)) AS DATETIME)
```

for your query

```
select * from News_Table
where (DATEDIFF( DAY , CAST((LEFT(NewsDate, 4) + SUBSTRING(NewsDate, 6 ,2) + RIGHT(NewsDate, 2)) AS DATETIME)
                     , CAST((LEFT(@Todaydate, 4) + SUBSTRING(@Todaydate, 6 ,2) + RIGHT(@Todaydate, 2)) AS DATETIME)
                ) <= @Count)
```

**Note**

If variable `@Todaydate` is actually storing today's date then why not use simply `GETDATE()` function.